# UTF-8 for japanese

Tags: java, utf

I am getting following string in json response

移動ピンポイントにお付き合いいただきましてありがとうございましたm(_ _)m By P2235465 #colopl_a http://t.co/LSxAxTGGd9

but after utf-8 conversion i am getting this string

ç§»å‹•ãƒ”ãƒ³ãƒ�ã‚¤ãƒ³ãƒˆã�«ã�Šä»˜ã��å�ˆã�„ã�„ã�Ÿã� ã��ã�¾ã�—ã�¦ã�‚ã‚Šã�Œã�¨ã�†ã�”ã�–ã�„ã�¾ã�—ã�Ÿm (__)m By P2235465 #colopl_a http://t.co/LSxAxTGGd9

I am doing conversion in java for some string i am getting proper output. Could it be the case of UTF-16 encoding or i am doing something wrong

Here's the code for reference

```
String finalOutput = "";
 StringEntity inputRequest = new StringEntity(g.toJson(gt), "UTF-8");
        inputRequest.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(inputRequest);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String outputContent;
        while ((outputContent = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (finalOutput == null) {
                finalOutput = outputContent;
            } else {
                finalOutput += "\n" + outputContent;
            }
        }
            byte contentByte[];

    try {
        contentByte = finalOutput.getBytes("UTF-8");
        finalOutput = new String(contentByte,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return finalOutput;
```

Comment: It could be a Japanese encoding, take a look at this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_encoding).

Comment: @CeilingGecko Is it different from UTF-8

Comment: General practice is that json is sent as UTF-8. So the only moment of conversion would be from `byte[]` / `InputStream` to `String` / `Reader`. There the encoding is critical. It however reminds of UTF-8 bytes twice encoded to UTF-8. On a non-UTF8 Windows system with once an encoding parameter left out and defaulting to the OS encoding. Give code.

Comment: @JoopEggen I added code to question

Comment: Is this code being run on a Windows machine? If so, I think the problem is that you are changing the encoding twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overloaded version of the InputStreamReader *with* encoding. Only that is portable on every platform.

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent()),
               StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // Or "UTF-8"
```

For stylistic reasons one better uses StandardCharsets.UTF_8.

A StringBuilder outputContent would definetely be better; but as already commented by others, the conversion between bytes and String happens too often. Maybe consider **ByteArrayOutputStream**.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String outputContent;
    while ((outputContent = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(outputContent).append('\n');
    }

    br.close();

    return= sb.toString(); // Final result, no more
```